# ELM model and Data from Rest Json

Tags: python, json, rest, elm

In most examples models are build with existing field/ data we are aware of as example,

```
type alias Model =
  { topic : String
  , gifUrl : String
  }
```

Supposed i m building an application where i need to perform CRUD operations via REST and some of the fields are not know before hand which is more handy for Unit testing and Rapid development.

How do we model dynamic fields generated from REST/JSON ?

Comment: What do expect to be done with unknown fields? Your decoders don't have to pull out all fields or match your model precisely. Are you perhaps trying to echo the unknown fields unchanged from a `GET` request to a `PUT`?

Comment: Yes, GETing custom fields and POSTing the related data into the server or loading lists with variable fields, into a table

Comment: You could use [`dict`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Json-Decode#dict) to first decode into a dictionary and only operate on the known fields

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the dynamic fields in a [Maybe](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Maybe#Maybe) or using a [Dict](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Dict) each have their own drawbacks in this situation; is the field `Nothing` because it hasn't loaded yet, or because it failed?

The [RemoteData type](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/krisajenkins/remotedata/latest/RemoteData) is better suited here; by representing each of the four states (Not asked, Loading, Failure, and Success) it allows code like this:

```
view : Model -> Html msg
view model =
  case model.news of
    NotAsked -> text "Initialising."

    Loading -> text "Loading."

    Failure err -> text ("Error: " ++ toString err)

    Success news -> viewNews news


viewNews : News -> Html msg
viewNews news =
    div []
        [h1 [] [text "Here is the news."]
        , ...]
```

The article [How Elm Slays a UI Antipattern](http://blog.jenkster.com/2016/06/how-elm-slays-a-ui-antipattern.html) explains it in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic fields are not possible as you should have the structure to be same thoughout the execution of program. you might wanna do something like

```
type alias Model =
  { topic : String
  , gifUrl : String
  , field1 : String
  , person : Maybe Person
  }
```

the fields with Maybe represents optional fields

And you should use decoders for decoding json
[link](https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/json.html)